# JSON object memory allocation vs variable

Tags: javascript

I have a question related to memory allocation of JSON object. Will JSON take more memory than individual variable. For Ex:

```
var testVar1 = "testVar1"; //  8*2 bytes for char + integer pointer (8bytes)
var testVar2 = "testVar1";//  8*2 bytes for char + integer pointer (8bytes)
var testVar3 = "testVar1";//  8*2 bytes for char + integer pointer (8bytes)

vs
testVariables = {
"testVar1":"testVar1",
"testVar2":"testVar2",
"testVar3":"testVar3"
}
```

When I  open up memory profiler, testVariables retain memory seem to be more than sum of individual variable memory( retain). Please let me know which is a better solution

Comment: You don't seem to understand what JSON is. JSON is a *string* containing a representation of an object. What you have there is three string variables, and one object.

Comment: Of course an object takes up more memory than the sum of its property values. If nothing else, the property names need to be stored as well.

Comment: Also each "var" has its own prototype chain. This add a lot more to the object itself.

Comment: @HristoStaykov: *"Also each "var" has its own prototype chain."* Uh, no. Variables don't have prototype chains. Objects do. But strings are not objects.

Comment: @FelixKling you are right. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

When you create 3 new variables, the Javascript engine will be create 3 new properties in the scope object and affect their values.

When you create a object witch contain 3 property. The engine create 1 new property to the scope object. It affect a new instance of Object to it that contain the 3 property references and their values.

So in second case you have 1 reference and 1 object instance more than the first case.